# Building long string literals without + operator

Tags: java, string, performance, string-concatenation

people. I wonder whether it is possible in Java. I want to log a long string message. For example

"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"

But to keep my source code readable I don't want to write it in one line since otherwise any code reader will have to scroll all the time. So I wrote it like

"aaaaaaaaaaa" +
"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" +
"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"

However, since Java creates a new object for each string, and for concatenation it creates even more temporary objects, this kind of notation produces plenty of overhead. The construct is in a loop in my code, so performance issue is very important.

Are there any other ways to write the string efficiently? I searched the web but did not find anything except for using StringBuffer.

BR
Ewgenij

Comment: Concatenation using + in one statement is actually compiled to the use of StringBuilder (at least for Sun Java6 compilers). So it’s no surprise that there is no difference between these two options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the strings are known at compile time, they will be concatenated automatically, so you don't have any penalties at all.

If the strings are generated at runtime, use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) (not a [`StringBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html), it's slower because of the synchronization overhead).

Answer (score 0):

[If the string can be evaluated at compile time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28), the compiler will take care of combining them for you then. If you're building long strings at runtime, use a `StringBuilder`.

Here's an example of how the compiler deals with concatenation at compile time:

**Source**

```
String foo = "asdf" + "fdsa";
```

**Class file**

```
Constant pool:
 #1 = Methodref          #6.#17         //  java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
 #2 = String             #18            //  asdffdsa
...
#18 = Utf8               asdffdsa
```

Comment: `StringBuilder` will be used anyway to evaluate a single concatenation expression.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Nope, the concatenated string goes in the constant pool.

Comment: Only if all the parts are compile-time constants. My comment is a reply to yours "if you're building long strings at runtime, use a `StringBuilder`". If the building happens inside a single concatenation expression, it will implicitly be evaluated using a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Ah, got it.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("aaaaaaaaaaa");
builder.append("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
builder.append("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");

builder.toString(); //This returns "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
```

However, in your case, with hard-coded string, doing

```
String msg = "aaaaaaa" +
"aaaaaaa" +
"aaaaaaa"
```

Will compile into

```
String msg = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
```

Comment: This isn't a good option for the case described, where all the parts of the string are known at compile time, since this will force rebuilding the string at runtime.